# How to fix Problem playing Youtube videos in firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash, youtube

I am using Firefox as my browser and when I am using youtube and play any video on it. Not the video and audio they both are not coming continuously. They are coming with an interval.

Its like the audio is stuck somewhere. I think maybe its my flash player plugin.

Comment: Try reinstalling firefox and also the plugins!

Comment: Also you can try to switch to HTML5 player. For doing that visit http://youtube.com/html5 and follow the instructions there.